# R - join data frames and filter whole groups

Tags: r, join, filter, dplyr

I have three data frames with different recipes that I got from a website.
The first one is for pancakes; the second one is for French toast; the third is for eggs benedict. Then I combine these three tables into one table that I call recipes_list.

```
# pancakes
# Good Old Fashioned Pancakes
ingredients <- c("flour", "baking powder", "salt", "white sugar", "milk", "egg(s)", "butter")
amount <- c(1.5, 3.5, 1, 1, 1.25, 1, 3)
measure <- c("cup(s)", "teaspoon(s)", "teaspoon(s)", "tablespoon(s)", "cup(s)", "", "tablespoon(s)") 
pancake_data <- data.frame(ingredients, amount, measure)
pancake_data <- pancake_data %>%
  mutate(recipe = "pancakes")

# french toast
# Vanilla-Almond Spiced French Toast
ingredients <- c("milk", "sugar", "egg(s)", "vanilla extract", "cinnamon", "nutmeg", "allspice", "toast")
amount <- c(2, 2, 4, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 8)
measure <- c("cup(s)", "tablespoon(s)", "", "teaspoon(s)", "teaspoon(s)", "teaspoon(s)", "teaspoon(s)", "slice(s)") 
french_toast_data <- data.frame(ingredients, amount, measure)
french_toast_data <- french_toast_data %>%
  mutate(recipe = "vanilla-almond spiced french toast")

# eggs benedict
ingredients <- c("egg yolk(s)", "lemon juice", "pepper", "Worcestershire sauce", "water", "butter", "salt", "eggs", "white vinegar", "Canadian-style bacon", "English muffins", "butter")
amount <- c(4, 3.5, 1, 0.125, 1, 1, 0.25, 8, 1, 8, 4, 2)
measure <- c("", "tablespoon(s)", "pinch", "teaspoon(s)", "tablespoon(s)", "cup", "teaspoon(s)", "", "teaspoon(s)", "strip(s)", "", "tablespoon(s)") 
eggs_benedict_data <- data.frame(ingredients, amount, measure)
eggs_benedict_data <- eggs_benedict_data %>%
  mutate(recipe = "eggs benedict")

recipe_list <- rbind(pancake_data, french_toast_data, eggs_benedict_data)
```

Now let's say I take stock of what is in the fridge and I come up with this table:

```
current_fridge <- c("flour", "baking powder", "salt", "white sugar", "milk", "egg(s)", "butter", "milk", "sugar", "egg(s)", "vanilla extract", "cinnamon", "nutmeg", "toast")
amount <- c(1.5, 3.5, 1, 1, 1.25, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 8)
measure <- c("cup(s)", "teaspoon(s)", "teaspoon(s)", "tablespoon(s)", "cup(s)", "", "tablespoon(s)","cup(s)", "tablespoon(s)", "", "teaspoon(s)", "teaspoon(s)", "teaspoon(s)", "slice(s)") 
current_fridge_data <- data.frame(current_fridge, amount, measure)
```

I understand I could use a semi-join or something like this in order to filter down recipe_list by what is in current_fridge_data. But how can I make it so that I only include recipes that have all the available ingredients (not missing a single one?) I'm trying to create a new dataframe that I could call: possible_recipes_given_ingredients. And is there a flexible answer, in case I wanted to add eggs florentine or something else?

Comment: Hi @RonakShah sorry for the late reply. I spend some time re-thinking this question so that it would make more sense and I've been back-and-forth on it. I think recipes is a good placeholder here. So I re-wrote the question. I hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `recipe` you can check if all the ingredients required are present in the fridge as well as the quantity that is present in the fridge is greater than equal to required to prepare the recipe.

```
library(dplyr)

recipe_list %>%
  left_join(current_fridge_data, by = c('ingredients' = 'current_fridge')) %>%
  group_by(recipe) %>%
  summarise(all_ingredient_present= all(amount.x <= amount.y & !is.na(amount.y)))

# recipe                             all_ingredient_present
#  <chr>                              <lgl>                 
#1 eggs benedict                      FALSE                 
#2 pancakes                           TRUE                  
#3 vanilla-almond spiced french toast FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an if statement to determine if french_toast_data should be appended or not. Check if each unique element of current_fridge_data is found in french_toast_data. If the answer is no, then don't even put french_toast_data into what_can_I_make. If the comparison returns all TRUE's then the sum will be equal to the length of unique(current_fridge_data)

```
what_can_I_make <- ()

if (sum(unique(current_fridge_data$list) %in% unique(french_toast_data$list)) == length(unique(current_fridge_data$list))) {
  
  what_can_I_make <- rbind(what_can_I_make, french_toast_data)
  
}
```

Comment: HI @andrea thank you for the suggestion. This seems like a super smart solution but I'm not sure it's flexible enough. I just re-wrote the question after spending a day coming up with a better example. This new example also has another table.

Comment: I accepted the renaming suggestions for the solution to match the new example. Based on how the example is presented now, Ronak's approach is far batter.